# ASP.Net Web API routing for multiple GET methods

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes

I've got an existing ASP.Net Web API with the default routing:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

I've got a controller - TestController and I want to have a number of GET methods within this controller e.g.:

```
public IHttpActionResult MethodA() -> http://....../api/Test/MethodA
public IHttpActionResult MethodB() -> http://....../api/Test/MethodB
```

Is there any way I could do something like this without modifying the existing routing and breaking the current controllers/routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Route attribute to your methods, like

```
[Route("MethodA")]
[Route("MethodB")]
```

Comment: This worked but I also had to add a RoutePrefix attribute to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
```

into

```
   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
```

Comment: I'd rather not as that would mean testing all the existing controllers. Adding Route and RoutePrefix attributes worked.